# What is the default superuser password of Liberte Linux

Tags: linux, sudo, password

In Liberte Linux ,When we install it then root password is "liberte". Please let me know superuser password . I need to  change file permission after entering in superuser mode.

Comment: `root` == superuser

Answer (score 0):

Please state your question in understandable language!

to change a password for a user type:

```
passwd <user>
```

if you are not root try

```
sudo passwd <user>
```